# Sorting by distance with Titanium alloy models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, titanium, titanium-alloy

I recently used Titanium and Alloy to develop an android application. Now I'm trying (for the first time) to sort a bound backbone collection by distance with a comparator function, but it doesn't work.

```
comparator: function(game) {
    var lon1, lat1, lat2, lon2;
    if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
        Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
            if (e.error) {
                Ti.API.error('Error:' + e.error);
                return 0;
            } else {
                Ti.API.info(e.coords);

                lon1 = e.coords.longitude;
                lat1 = e.coords.latitude;

                Titanium.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(game.get("camp"), function(e) {
                    if (e.success) {
                        lat2 = e.latitude;
                        lon2 = e.longitude;

                        var R = 6371; // km
                        var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
                        var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
                        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                            Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
                            Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
                        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                        var d = R * c;

                        console.log("KM: " + parseInt(d));

                        return parseInt(d);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unable to find address");

                        return 0;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('please enable location services')

        return 0;
    }
}
```

In my controller, I use:

```
var games = Alloy.Collections.allGames;
games.sort();
games.fetch();
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use neither Titanium or Alloy, but I can see why your comparator function won't work.

## Backbone collection's `comparator` property

First, to see why it doesn't work, you need to understand what's the collection's `comparator` property, what's available and how to implement one.

There are (at least) 3 types of value a collection's `comparator` property can take.

- The name of an attribute as a string

  ```
  comparator: 'fieldName'
  ```
- A [`sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) function which takes a single argument

  ```
  comparator: function(model) {
      // return a numeric or string value by which the model 
      // should be ordered relative to others.
      return Math.sin(model.get('myNumber'));
  }
  ```
- A [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function that expects two arguments

  ```
  comparator: compare(modelA, modelB) {
      var field = 'myNumber',
          numA = modelA.get(field),
          numB = modelB.get(field);
      if (numA < numB) {
          return -1;
      }
      if (numA > numB) {
          return 1;
      }
      // a must be equal to b
      return 0;
  }
  ```

## Why yours fails?

The short answer: It only ever returns `undefined` or `0` depending on the value of `Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled`.

You have made a convoluted function to sort your models in which you use asynchronous functions (`getCurrentPosition`, `forwardGeocoder`) and you put all the logic inside callbacks which are evaluated when the collection has already finished sorting.

Comment: I understand, ty a lot!